# Sitecore headless qraphql get latest version in search query

Tags: graphql, sitecore, headless

I am working on sitecore headless project writing a graphql search query to fetch search base results for front-end website, the issue is query is returning all versions items from the master and web database both.

I have to use only web version that is latest version which is published from master database, below is the query and result in screenshot:

Query:

```
query titleSearch {
  TitleSearch: search(
    where: {
      name: "_path"
      value: "{id of specific content tree node}"
      operator: EQ
      AND:
      [
         { 
            name: "_language"
            value: "en"
            operator: EQ
          }
          { 
            name: "pageTitle"
            value: "in-flight"
            operator: EQ
          }
      ]
    }
    first: 10
    after: ""
    orderBy: { name: "pageTitle", direction: ASC }
  ) {
    Total: total
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNext
    }
    Results: results {
      ... on Item {
          pageTitle:field(name:"pageTitle"){            
            value
          }
          url {
            value: path
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want published items from the web database, so if that's the case, just configure your endpoint to use the web database.
When configuring the edge endpoint, you can configure your schema providers and tell them where to get their data

```
<schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
<content ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/content/schemaProviders/edgeContent" param1="context"/>
</schema>
```

If you look at the `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeContent.config` configuration file, you can see that this configuration is switched by role (ContentDelivery,ContentManagement,Standalone), so that specifying a correct database name as `param1` (web, master, context), that will correctly configure the  element in the referred to configuration path.

If you really do need access to items in both databases, then you might want two separate endpoints that differ by URL and that `param1` attribute.